# 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime' in python

Tags: python, datetime, arcgis, arcpy

hi i have long code maybe if you wanna check it out tell me, so im trying to solve this and I'm pretty sure the code is right but it keeps getting me the same error, i try everything to solve it but its the same i checked if the attribute missing but its there i don't know what i have done wrong
this is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import time
import pickle
import os
import numpy as np
import xgboost
import pytz
import arcgis
#
#plotting
#'''
from IPython.display import HTML, display
import datashader as ds
from datashader import transfer_functions as tf
from datashader.colors import colormap_select, Greys9, Hot, viridis, inferno
#'''

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from matplotlib.ticker import NullFormatter
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('xtick', color='k')
mpl.rc('ytick', color='k')
%matplotlib inline
#'''
import datetime
from pandas import Series
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta


predTimest = pd.date_range('01/06/2017', periods=7*24, freq='H',tz='US/Mountain')
predTimest
n [28]:


predTimest


Out[28]:
DatetimeIndex(['2017-01-06 00:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-06 01:00:00-07:00',
               '2017-01-06 02:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-06 03:00:00-07:00',
               '2017-01-06 04:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-06 05:00:00-07:00',
               '2017-01-06 06:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-06 07:00:00-07:00',
               '2017-01-06 08:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-06 09:00:00-07:00',
               ...
               '2017-01-12 14:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-12 15:00:00-07:00',
               '2017-01-12 16:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-12 17:00:00-07:00',
               '2017-01-12 18:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-12 19:00:00-07:00',
               '2017-01-12 20:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-12 21:00:00-07:00',
               '2017-01-12 22:00:00-07:00', '2017-01-12 23:00:00-07:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, US/Mountain]', length=168, freq='H')
prediction_time = predTimest[15]
test_df = shapefile.copy()
test_df['timestamp'] = prediction_time
test_df['allah1__27'] = shapefile.allah1__27.astype('int64')
test_df['hour'] = prediction_time.hour
test_df['weekday'] = prediction_time.weekday()
test_df['month'] = prediction_time.month
def add_join_key(df):
    df['join_key'] = df.allah1__27.map(int).map(str)+df.timestamp.map(datetime.datetime.isoformat)
    df = df.set_index('join_key')
    return df
weath_df = wdf.loc[prediction_time]
test_df = add_join_key(test_df)
weath_df = add_join_key(weath_df.reset_index())
```

and it give me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-4714b1ff587e> in <module>
----> 1 test_df = add_join_key(test_df)
      2 weath_df = add_join_key(weath_df.reset_index())

<ipython-input-63-1a4e6a6f2c07> in add_join_key(df)
      1 def add_join_key(df):
----> 2     df['join_key'] = df.allah1__27.map(int).map(str)+df.timestamp.map(datetime.datetime.isoformat)
      3     df = df.set_index('join_key')
      4     return df

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Comment: remove one of datetime

Answer (score 0):

You have imported datetime twice at the top of your script with the last import taking precedence:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

Therefore you should be calling:

```
datetime.isoformat
```

Comment: i did that before i got this error  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'allah1__27'

Comment: Then the DataFrame object you are passing to `add_join_key` does not have that column present. It is probably linked to this df `weath_df` since the `test_df` has the column you are specifying.

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: Create another question. This is unrelated to what your problem was here

Comment: i did here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388516/attributeerror-dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-allah1-27

Answer (score 0):

You should not `import datetime` and also `from datetime import datetime`. Best practice would be to just `import datetime` and then if you want the deeper module call `datetime.datetime` otherwise you are creating two things with the **exact same name**...obviously this would lead to confusion. If you really want to import both then rename one like

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as datet
```

Now you can refer to one as `datetime` and the other as `datet` instead of having **both** of them refer to the same name "`datetime`"

Comment: @reedinarioner i did that already, but I don't know what are you meaning by that "exact same name"

Comment: @reedinarioner i did what you say i import datetime only and i get  AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'isoformat'

Comment: Right. If you've renamed it then it would be `datet.isoformat`. After renaming it you have to use the new name to access it

Comment: still the same ```def add_join_key(df):
    df['join_key'] = df.allah1__27.map(int).map(str)+df.timestamp.map(datet.isoformat)
    df = df.set_index('join_key')
    return df``` ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'allah1__27'```