# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'allah1__27'

Tags: python, datetime, machine-learning, arcpy

I'm trying to solve this and I'm pretty sure the code is right but it keeps getting me the same Error.

I have tried this:

```py
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as datet

test_df = shapefile.copy()
test_df['timestamp'] = prediction_time
test_df['allah1__27'] = shapefile.allah1__27.astype('int64')
test_df['hour'] = prediction_time.hour
test_df['weekday'] = prediction_time.weekday()
test_df['month'] = prediction_time.month
def add_join_key(df):
    df['join_key'] = df.allah1__27.map(int).map(str)+df.timestamp.map(datetime.isoformat)
    df = df.set_index('join_key')
    return df
weath_df = wdf.loc[prediction_time]
test_df = add_join_key(test_df)
weath_df = add_join_key(weath_df.reset_index())
```

And I get this Error:

```sh
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'isoformat'
```

Also I tried:

```py
def add_join_key(df):
    df['join_key'] = df.allah1__27.map(int).map(str)+df.timestamp.map(datet.isoformat)
    df = df.set_index('join_key')
    return df
weath_df = wdf.loc[prediction_time]
test_df = add_join_key(test_df)
weath_df = add_join_key(weath_df.reset_index())
```

And I get this Error:

```sh
AttributeError: DataFrame' object has no attribute 'allah1__27'
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

For the first error: the method isoformat is from datetime that's a method of datetime.

You should:

`import datetime
datetime.datetime.isoformat`

Or:

`from datetime import datetime as datet
datet.isoformat`

As for the second error:
df is a dictionary, i think you should call it:

```
 df['join_key'] = df['allah1__27'].map(int).....
```

Comment: @leardoArnsGonzales i used datet.isoformat and i got ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: could you show the code where you use it? Or the message error? It may be something with the value you are passing